# Python: importing a global variable into a local variable and then exporting into a global variable again

Tags: python

So I have something like this:

```
var1 = 6
var2 = 8
def somefunction(thing):
    thing += 1
```

Now I want to make it so that `somefunction(var1)` actually makes `var1` equal `7` globally. I looked around and I can't seem to find a good way to do this. Am I being thick? Sorry if this is obvious, I only started learning Python a couple days ago. Thanks.

@edit Ok, answered. Apparently it can't be done the way I wanted. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Just have `somefunction()` *return* the new value:

```
def somefunction(thing):
    return thing + 1

var1 = somefunction(var1)
```

You can't alter other references to a value; you pass in the value, not the name. `thing` is set to `6` in your example, not `var1`.

You could use a dictionary in place of a namespace, but you'll still need to pass in the *name*, not the variable:

```
namespace = {
    'var1': 6,
    'var2': 8,
}

def somefunction(thing):
    namespace[thing] += 1

somefunction('var1')
```

Now we are naming what key in a global dictionary to alter, rather than passing in the value that that key references. You could do the same with the `globals()` dictionary, but then you run the risk of accidentally modifying globals outside of your constrained set of names you want to treat this way.

You may want to read the excellent [*Python Names and Values* blogpost](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) by Ned Batchelder in this context.

Comment: But the way that I actually have this thing set up it's functions nested inside functions and I can't predict what will be put in where and this way you described isn't really feasible. Can't I do it from within the function somehow?

Comment: @frhrpr: do *what* from the function? Set arbitrary global variables based on the value you passed in? No, because values don't track what references them.

Comment: @frhrpr It sounds like you have a design problem

Comment: @frhrpr: added an additional option; without more details it does sound like you have a design issue on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = 6

def somef()
    global var1
    var1+= 1
```

Comment: So how would the OP change `var2`? There is a reason they wanted to pass in `var1` as an argument.

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about var2, did he?

Comment: So why do you think they mentioned `var1` and `var2`, and passed in `var1` as an argument?

Comment: No idea, am I supposed to know that? All I'm trying to do is answer the question of how to change a global variable inside a function. And as far as I can see, that's what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @frhrpr: then *update your question*. There's a lot of downvoting going on here over different interpretations of your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in Python to reassign a variable in a caller from inside a called function.

```
var1 = 6

def cant_be_done(v):
    v += 1

cant_be_done(var1)
assert var1 == 6
```

For more detail about why, see [Python Names and Values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)